# Why does Visual Studio 2015 ask me to log into SQL databases when I open a solution?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 has recently started prompting me to log into SQL databases when I initially open a solution. It only asks me to log into databases on the same SQL server, and it prompts me to log into each of databases that appear in Web.configs. I don't want it to ask me to log in, and even if I try to log in with the correct db name/user/pass, it doesn't work.

This only started happening the past few days. I haven't installed any new extensions, though some extensions may have automatically updated. How can I turn this off?

[image]

Comment: Because you added the connection to SQL or Server Explorer at some point, without saving the password? VS does *not* ask to connect to SQL Server by itself.

Comment: It seems there are Data Connections in Server Explorer. Although I've deleted them, after restarting Visual Studio they reappear. However, it's no longer prompting me to log into these db's now.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to determine the root cause of this issue, however, I was able to get Visual Studio to stop prompting me for the login after I fixed the login information (connection strings) in the relevant `Web.config` files (it was wrong in some of the web.configs, which seems to be why I was getting prompted). Removing the data sources from Server Explorer did *not* work - they just reappeared after closing/reopening the solution.

I still don't know why this started happening. I've been using Visual Studio for years and I can't think of a time when I was prompted for a db login.